# Error on inserting into SQLite table with Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms application that works fine on Android, but when I run on iOS, I get this error when I set up the database

`Method not found: string SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_column_name(SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt,int)`

and then when I try to insert into the database table

`Method not found: string SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_errmsg(SQLitePCL.sqlite3)`

The application uses mvvmlight and I have the sqlite-net-pcl package installed there and also in the platform code. The versions all marry up.

My iOS initialising code for sqlite looks like this (on the platform)

```
public class SQLiteConnectionFactory : ISqliteConnectionFactory
{
    readonly string Filename = "mydb";

    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        path = Path.Combine(path, Filename);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISqliteConnectionFactory, SQLiteConnectionFactory>();
        return new SQLiteConnection(path, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);
    }
```

and the insert code (in the mvvmlight project) like this

```
public void SaveListData<T>(List<T> toStore)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (dbLock)
            {
                connection.InsertAll(toStore);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I've had issues with Xam.Android and sqlite-net-pcl, but never on iOS

I have the sqlite-net-pcl 1.7.302-beta and SQLitePCL.* 2.0.2 packages installed (using the beta version to prevent some of the linking issues on the stable version)

Below is a shot of the iOS packages installed

[image: installed packages for iOS]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677286/xamarin-form-sqlite-connection-method-not-found-int-sqlite-sqliteconnection-c

Comment: That looks like an Android solution rather than iOS. I've already done the uninstall-reinstall of the packages and nothing

Comment: Make sure that you had udate the version of XF to the latest version both in Share project and iOS project .

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your sqlite-net-pcl package to version 1.5.231, that did the job for me